# Where to store page titles and meta descriptions of subpages?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-data, meta-tags

For the website I work on, all page data is in database (page title, meta tags, content),
and I store all that in one table.

Now, I have a page "products", which has a number of sub-pages (each representing a different product).

My question is, what is the best place for storing title and meta tags of sub-pages?
I thought of simply adding these columns to "products" table, but it somehow feels wrong

(having for example "page_title" in two different tables).

Any totally different, wiser way to do it is also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your product have a name? if so - why not to use it as a title?

Comment: Yes, I definitely should do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have one table for pages (including products) and another table for storing sub-pages relationships (i.e., product X is a subpage of page Products).

Comment: Sounds good, but as my "products" table has a number of columns which have no relation to main pages, that would make my "pages" table very denormalized

Comment: Then you could store a string representation (JSON for example) of an array of sub-pages titles and meta-tags directly to a column of your product table, as you suggested:

    `$column = json_encode(array(array('title' => 'X',
                                      'meta' => 'XX'),
                                array('title' => 'Y',
                                      'meta' => 'YY')));
    
    // Insert $column to database`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'pages' table as the main table, and add associate a product to a page.

Then in your page table you can have a parent/child relationship.